# ServiceStack with Protobuf format

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack, protobuf-net, webservice-client

I am trying to use protobuf format in ServiceStack Webservices ( following the example at [ServiceStack: REST with ProtoBuf by Steven Hollidge](http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.in/2012/04/servicestack-rest-with-protobuf.html). I have added a Winform application to consume the webservice. The codes are given below.

**HelloService.cs**

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using ProtoBuf;
using ServiceStack.Demo.Rest;
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;

namespace ServiceStack.Demo.WebService
{
[DataContract] 
public class Hello
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
 [DataContract] 
public class HelloResponse
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Result { get; set; }
}

 public class HelloService : RestServiceBase<Hello>
{
    public  override object OnGet(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
    }
}
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Funq;
using ServiceStack.Demo.Rest;
using ServiceStack.Demo.WebService;
using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;

namespace ServiceStack.Demo
{
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("ServiceStack makes services easy!", typeof (AppHost).Assembly)
    {
        ServiceStack.Plugins.ProtoBuf.AppStart.Start();
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Routes
          .Add<Hello>("/hello")
          .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name}");

    }
 }

public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AppHost().Init();
    }
}
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ServiceStack.ServiceClient;
using ProtoBuf;
using ServiceStack.Plugins.ProtoBuf;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web;

namespace client
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ServiceClientBase _client;
    private const string Url = "http://localhost/servicestack.demo/servicestack/hello?format=x-protobuf";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this._client =
            new ProtoBufServiceClient(Url);

        var response = _client.Send<HelloResponse>(new Hello {Name = "ProtoBuf"});
        label1.Text = response.Result;
    }

   
    public class Hello
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    
    public class HelloResponse
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting `System.InvalidOperationException: Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: client.Form1+Hello`

What am I doing wrong? Please suggest.....

Comment: Just to make sure it isn't to do with the nested naming of the class, move the type Hello so its not nested in the Form1 Class.

Comment: Did that, Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: client.Hello occured at  var response = _client.Send<HelloResponse>(new Hello {Name = "ProtoBuf"});

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have your `Hello` class and your `HelloResponse` class declared twice. Once in **HelloService.cs** and again as inner classes in **Form.cs**. Removing the duplicates from your **Form.cs** file should allow your `ProtoBufServiceClient` to reference the correct classes/types.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the Form1.cs to the following and now it is working fine( refer to http://upjnv.blogspot.in/

```
 using System;  
 using System.Windows.Forms;  
 using ServiceStack.Plugins.ProtoBuf;  
 using System.Runtime.Serialization;  
 using ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web;  

namespace client  

{  

 public partial class Form1 : Form  

 {  

private ServiceClientBase _client;  

private const string Url = "http://localhost/servicestack.demo/servicestack/";  

public Form1()  

{  

  InitializeComponent();  

}  

private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  

{  

  this._client =  

    new ProtoBufServiceClient(Url);  

  var response = _client.Send<HelloResponse>("GET","/hello",new Hello {Name = "ProtoBuf"});  

  label1.Text = response.Result;  

 }  

 }  

[DataContract]  

public class Hello  

{  

[DataMember(Order = 1)]  

public string Name { get; set; }  

}  

[DataContract]  

public class HelloResponse  

 {  

[DataMember(Order = 1)]  

public string Result { get; set; }  

 } 



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your POCO classes in the same namespace, that should do it.

Comment: it is in the same namespace. what is this error:=> Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: client.Hello occured at var response = _client.Send<HelloResponse>(new Hello {Name = "ProtoBuf"});